# Problem with conversion

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class:

```
      template<class T>
        class MyClass
        {
        public:
                class Iterator {
    public:
    Iterator(MyClass<T>&){/*some code*/};
    };


  operator Iterator();
    Iterator& begin();
        };

    template<class T>
    MyClass<T>::operator typename MyClass<T>::Iterator()
    {
        return MyClass::Iterator(*this);
    }

    template<class T>
    typename MyClass<T>::Iterator& MyClass<T>::begin()
    {
        return *this;//<---------------cannot convert from MyClass to MyClass<T>::Iterator
    }
```

Why am I getting an error? I've provided conversion operator so everything should be fine.

Comment: You could just as well remove the conversion, because Iterator's constructor already allows the same conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`begin()` cannot return a reference to an `Iterator`; it needs to return an `Iterator` by value.

When the user-declared conversion to `Iterator` is called, it yields a temporary `Iterator` object.  A non-const reference cannot be bound to a temporary, hence the error you get when `begin()` returns a reference.

That said, having a conversion function that returns an `Iterator` is unusual at best.

Comment: my bad I just didn't put it into example. Fix it in a sec.